# Doppler effect and the mathematics involved?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functions, physics, mathematical-physics

I am doing the doppler effect for my high school project, and I was wondering if it will be a good project to talk about and if it would have some calculus involved? So what math could be involved also if you can please share some sources that show the math involved.