# Resources for Doppler effect.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, physics, graphing-functions, curves

I am an undergraduate student and I can barely find a resource that shows the math involved with the doppler effect such as calculus, change in frequency, etc. I already asked so many questions about this topic but your help is very useful.

Comment: Is this related to the high school project in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3711359/27978?

Comment: Yes, it is, but sadly no one helped me with anything.

Comment: Lots of GeoGebra resources on the Doppler effect https://www.geogebra.org/search/doppler

Comment: This might be a good starting point: https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/schwartz/files/lecture21-doppler.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestions in the comments, I think a good starting point is to study the wave equation (see Wikipedia for example). Look at the simplest case of a one dimensional plane wave travelling in one direction, say positive $x$, and then ask yourself what happens when you change from a stationary reference frame to one travelling with constant speed $v_0$ in the $+x$ and $-x$ directions, i.e. $x'=x \mp v_0 t$.